# Plivo WebRTC Phone - Unavailable

Tags: javascript, webrtc, voice, plivo

I've tried to use Plivo WebRTC but it fails ( i've tried the online aws and local web ( source from git ) ).

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/plivowebrtc/phone.html
```

I've set the endpoint with Direct Dial, the login is successful, but every time i tried to call, the result is : onCallFailed:Unavailable . I tried using chrome

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you submitted a [support ticket](https://manage.plivo.com/contact/support/)? That would be the best way to get your problem solved.

Other things to consider:

- did you set your caller id in the direct dial app?
- do you see a red dot on the Chrome tab for this webpage and a black video camera icon on the right end of the address bar? It looks like this:
  [image: Plivo WebRTC microphone access notification icons]

Comment: yes i use support ticket ( Product Support ), no answer yet.

What i did:
 I download the quickstart . ( The one that looks like this :)
    https://s3.amazonaws.com/plivowebrtc/phone.html

Create and endpoint with Direct Dial on Plivo Account

Open the quickstart , then login using the endpoints and password.

after that i put the caller id : +62812xxxxxxxx .

The chrome tab have that video camera icon, i've allowed the microphone.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have to follow the instructions for Option 2: setup a route on your own web server. 
https://www.plivo.com/docs/getting-started/web-sdk/quick-start/

Also be sure to use HTTPS link for your client-side app. Finally, buy credit from Plivo so you can make voice calls to any number:
https://www.plivo.com/faq/basics/whats-the-difference-between-free-trial-account-and-developer-account/